# Calculation of the four-momentum of the $Z$ boson in a $pp \to Z +$ jet hard process

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, reference-frames, momentum, collision

[image]

This thread might be somewhat long. But I look forward to anyone helping me understand the following problem. Before that I will clarify how I understand and distinguish things such center of mass, center of mass frame and center of momentum frame. If my understanding is incorrect please point that out.

Center of mass: It's that point in a body/system that can be thought of as having mass: $M=/sum_i m_i$ where $m_i$ are the constituents of the object/system. It's position vector is $\vec R(t)=\frac 1 M \sum_i m_i \vec r(t)$.

Center of momentum frame: The center of mass point is at rest but not in the origin of the coordinate system.

Center of mass frame: The center of mass point is at rest and in the origin of the coordinate system.

Now, if we consider a pp hard scale collision at a center of mass energy of 13TeV, the lab frame is that the same time the center of mass  frame of the two protons.

What the problem is, is that the partons which are involved in the hard collision have different fractions of momenta of the protons, therefore in the lab frame the center of mass (point) of the two partons involved in the scattering/collision moves. That's why we boost in the direction in which the partonic COM moves, which is alongside the beam direction. In the boosted frame (relative to the Lab frame) the center of mass of the two partons, is at rest.

In this frame (partonic center of mass frame) the emitted particles i.e the Z-boson and the jet (if one can associate it (for the sake of the argument) with a particle) have opposite 3D momenta, so that the conservation of the momentum holds.

My first question is:

If we stay at the partonic center of frame, once the Z boson decays, how will the lepton pair be ejected: option 1 or option 2 or maybe some other way? Basically I am asking about the direction of the emitted leptons from the decay while still being in the partonic COM frame.

My other questions are:

In my class we said that we can find the $p_z$(four momenta, no vector sign) from $e+e-/\mu+ \mu-$.

First the claim was made that $P_T\ge 20 GeV$. I believe this cut off transverse momenta value acts like a filtering, it filters out all the leptons produced from the MPI (multi partonic interactions) and UE (underlying event) from the leptons produced in the hard partonic interaction/event.

Then it was said : $(p_{\mu+}+p_{\mu-})^2=M^2$ where $M_Z -...< M < M_Z+..$. The square of the sum of the four momenta of the detected particles (lepton pair. The detector can only detect the leptons, not the unstable particle) is equal to the rest mass of the unstable particle, in this case the Z-boson. The $M_Z-$ and $M_Z+$ implies that we are considering an interval with a small statistical error. My questions are the following:

1. W say that $P_T\ge 20 GeV$. Which frame of reference we consider when making this claim. This goes back to my first question. Personally I believe this is made relative to the  LAB frame= Hadronic (pp) COM frame. But I am not sure.
2. Let's say that we detect the leptons of the hard event, and we are able to measure the transverse momenta of them. How exactly do we find the four momenta of the Z-boson $p_Z$?
   If I consider the case of the Z-boson decaying into a muon/ anti-muon pair, for one of the leptons i.e the muon one has:  $p_{\mu^+}=(E,\vec p)^T=(\sqrt{m^2 + p^2}, \vec p)^T$. If we express $\vec p=(\vec p_T,p_z)$ than : $p_{\mu^+}=(\sqrt{m^2 + p_T^2 + p_z^2}, \vec p_T,p_z)^T$. The exact same thin can be said for $p_{\mu^-}$. We can plug in these expression for the four momenta of the lepton pair to : $(p_{\mu+}+p_{\mu-})^2=M^2$. And while we know the invariant masses of the leptons and their transverse momenta, I don't see any information regarding their momentum component in the z-direction. My guess is that we know the value of this component of the momentum, because we know the four momenta of the boosted frame/partonic COM frame. So would it be accurate to say:
   **The four momentum of the Z-boson is calculated as follows: 1) We find the mass from the square of the sum of the four momenta of the lepton pair. 2) We know the value of the component of the 3D momentum alongside the beam axis (z-axis in my case) because we boost the frame and thus we know the z-component of the momentum of the boosted frame. Than because of conservation of momentum the transverse momentum of the Z-boson is just a scalar sum of the transverse momenta of the lepton pair**

Note:

Both, option 1 and option 2 represent directions in the $xy$-plane. But if the direction in which the $Z$-boson is emitted (in the partonic COM frame) is taken to be the $y$-axis, than which are the directions that the leptons trace. In the $x$-direction, $y$-direction or something in between?